# jquery mouse over link that will highlight image position

Tags: jquery, html

With this script, when i mouse over the link it will highlight the image coordinate that i specify in the `<area>:`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">$(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();
    $('.squidheadlink').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#squidhead').mouseover();
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        $('#squidhead').mouseout();
    }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
});</script>

<p>This is just a simple <a class="squidheadlink" href="#" >example</a>of how the maps look.</p>

<area id="squidhead" href="#" shape="circle" coords="50,71,10" alt="Octoface" data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.6}' title="Metadata'd up a bit">
```

Now my problem now is that when i need to add multiple link that script would be too long to my liking and i believe there you should be a way to simplify it.What currently i am doing is to add this for each new link that point new position.

```
  $('.squidheadlink2').mouseover(function(e) {
            $('#squidhead2').mouseover();
        }).mouseout(function(e) {
            $('#squidhead2').mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    });
```

the function is same so how can i make it so that for different (link1),(link2) that share same image (position 1) and (link3),(link4) that share same image (position 2) can be set by class or id without adding new script for each new link and image position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give all of your links a common class name or something then write a function that will iterate over them and use $(this) on each one to get and assign things. Let me know if you need code.

The easiest way is to use custom attributes on the links like this..

```
<a href="" pairwith="squidhead1">link</a>
<a href="" pairwith="squidhead2">link</a>
<a href="" pairwith="squidhead3">link</a>
```

Then...

```
 $('[pairwith]').mouseover(function(e) {
            $('#'+ $(this).attr('pairwith')).mouseover();
        }).mouseout(function(e) {
            $('#'+ $(this).attr('pairwith')).mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    });
```

You are using a custom attribute to pair with the other items. Problem Solved.